# How do I map all these tables with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a table PATIENT which has some fields. There's also a CONTACT table that has a field called 'patientId' that needs to store PATIENT's ID (which is autogenerated), and a PATIENT_CONTACT table that only relates the two tables.

Now, here comes the tricky part. There are three other tables: CONTACT_ADDRESS, CONTACT_PHONE, CONTACT_EMAIL. A row in CONTACT will have the same ID as one (and only one) of CONTACT_ADDRESS, CONTACT_PHONE and CONTACT EMAIL. How do I get this all to work?

I have tried so many approaches, this is what I have right now:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient", schema = "patient")
public class PatientEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

   //... more fields

  @OneToOne
  private ContactEmailEntity contactEmailEntity;

  @OneToOne
  private ContactAddressEntity contactAddressEntity;

  @OneToOne
  private ContactPhoneEntity contactPhoneEntity;
}
```

The three CONTACT_* classes are similar and they look like this:

```
@Table(name = "contact_address", schema = "patient")
public class ContactAddressEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  // ... more fields

  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @MapsId
  private ContactEntity contact;
}
```

And my CONTACT class looks like this:

```
@Table(name = "contacto", schema = "paciente")
public class ContactEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

//... more fields
```

Can you see things that don't look right or could be done better? I get all sorts of errors with every approach. My latest one is:

```
ERROR: column patientent0_.contact_address_entity_contact_id does not exist
```

when trying to do a simple patient find. Please, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Given your description, a patient has many contacts (or just one if there is a unique constraint on contact.patient_id). And a contact has an address, an email and a phone. And the IDs of these three entities are derived from their parent contact's ID: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived.

Comment: @JBNizet a patient has many contacts and a contact has either an address, an email or a phone. If a patient wants to save an address and a phone, it would have two contacts. That link looks good!

Comment: Then The three classes should be subclasses of Contact: an address *is a* contact. A phone *is a* contact. You need to read the docuentation about inheritance.